# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, oscommerce

I'm working in OsCommerece and getting this up in my error log

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in public_html/includes/classes/seo.class.php(2206) : eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: what's on line 2206 in `seo.class.php`?

Comment: The first 16 lines aren't helping... You don't need to post them. Learn more about eval http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: Line 2206 =  eval("$cache_data");

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just remove the `<?php`, `?>` tags, as `seo.class.php` seems to run the input through [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

> **mixed eval(string $code)**
>
> The code mustn't be wrapped in opening and closing PHP
>   tags...

Comment: Tried removing the tags, broke the site...quickly put them back.

Comment: then you'll need to improve your answer and show us some surrounding code, f.e. what's in $cache_data ? where does it come from? can you place a `var_dump($cache_data)` before the `eval` on line 2206, and add that output to your answer?

Comment: Appreciate the help so far.

Had a look in the dbase at `$cache_data`  has a heap of numbers in it e.g S0lNy8xL1VD3dfQLdXN0Dg...

Placing `var_dump($cache_data)` resulted in this being display on screen
`string(92) "define('MANUFACTURER_NAME_2', 'sitename'); define('MANUFACTURER_NAME_3', 'productname'); "`

Comment: Lines 2178-2244 are here `http://pastebin.com/Q1W2an38` this is the function that line 2206 lives in. 

Happy to provide on info if needed

Comment: And right after the var_dump, you got the syntax error as in the title of your question?

Comment: Once I included the var_dump in the code I got this `string(92) "define('MANUFACTURER_NAME_2', 'sitename'); define('MANUFACTURER_NAME_3', 'productname'); "`

Comment: That was visable on the website its self at the top

Comment: since the eval is executed right after the var_dump, you should have seen the same error... It looks like something else is wrong in your code which you're not showing. I'm affraid I can't help you any further.